# Reducer not updating props in component correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux

My comments are dissappearing from my component after didMount() initializes them?  It's really strange!

React component:

```
componentDidMount = (post) => {
    const postId = this.props.post.id
    console.log('postpreview', postId)
    this.props.fetchComments(postId)
    console.log('postpreview comments:', this.props.comments)
  }
```

Redux Actions:

```
  export const beginFetchComments = () => ({
  type: C.BEGIN_FETCH_COMMENTS,
})

export const fetchCommentsFailed = (error) => ({
  type: C.FETCH_COMMENTS_FAILED,
  payload: { error },
})

export const fetchCommentsSuccess = (comments) => ({
  type: C.FETCH_COMMENTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: { comments }
})

export function fetchComments(postId) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(beginFetchComments());
    return fetch(`${api}/posts/${postId}/comments`, { headers })
      .then(
        res => res.json(),
        error => console.log('An error occurred at fetchComments', error)
      )
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(fetchCommentsSuccess(json));
        return json;
      });
  };
}
```

Redux Reducer (switch case):

```
case C.BEGIN_FETCH_COMMENTS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: true,
    error: null
  };


case C.FETCH_COMMENTS_SUCCESS:
    console.log(action.payload.comments);
    const comments = _.mapKeys(action.payload.comments)
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        comments,
      };
```

The console displays this for the same console.log(), (I can't get my hands on my props!):

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]0: {id: "894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g", parentId: "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd", timestamp: 1468166872634, body: "Hi there! I am a COMMENT.", author: "thingtwo", …}1: {id: "8tu4bsun805n8un48ve89", parentId: "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd", timestamp: 1469479767190, body: "Comments. Are. Cool.", author: "thingone", …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

commentsReducer.js:22 []
```

Comment: Does your reducer listen to `C.BEGIN_FETCH_COMMENTS`? If yes, please provide how you update the state for that case.

Comment: I updated the post to show my C.BEGIN_FETCH_COMMENTS

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the use of `mapKeys` here but what I would do is do a console.log to see if I'm getting an object and under what key there is a `comments` array:

```
case C.FETCH_COMMENTS_SUCCESS:
  console.log(action.payload.comments); // is this logging an array?
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    comments: action.payload.comments,
  };
```

Comment: There si an object with the array, but then it rerenders and the object is empty

Answer (score 0):

The bottom  code I posted is the console.log - the object appears populated and then rerenders empty